# Why won't file uploads work on the browser despite it working in Postman?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

I'm not sure why when making a POST request on Postman, I'm successfully storing the URLs in the DB by grabbing the file and retrieving its name.

But when I try it on the browser, I get a 500 error.  The auth token's coming back correctly, the logged data is also containing the correct information so it's not entirely clear to me what I'm doing wrong even though I'm doing it exactly the same way as how I'm doing it in Postman and it works fine there.

In the server logs I see an error that says: `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null` but as mentioned before - the upload works fine on Postman.

What could be issue?

Here's my JS:

```
const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
let authToken = localStorage.getItem('token');

const onFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fileUpload(selectedFile);
}

const onChange = (e) => {
    let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
    if (!files.length) {
        return;
    }
    createImage(files[0]);
}

const createImage = (file) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        setSelectedFile(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

const fileUpload = (selectedFile) => {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8005/api/file-upload';
    const formData = {file: selectedFile}

    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    }

    console.log(authToken);
    console.log(formData);
    console.log(headers);

    JSON.stringify(formData);
    axios.post(url, formData, {
        headers: headers
    }).then(resp => {
            console.log(resp);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

return (
    <form>
       <input type="file" onChange={onChange} name="userUpload" required/>
       <Button variant="primary" onClick={onFormSubmit}>Upload!</Button>
    </form>
);
```

Comment: Did you inspect the axios xhr in the browser console? Is it using `multipart/form-data`? Can you see the file in the posted data? The error means laravel borks when trying to access a file that it expects but isn't actually there.

Comment: @ChrisG In the console, I see `POST http://localhost:8005/api/file-upload 500 (Internal Server Error)`.  Yeah, I see the file in the posted data.

Comment: My guess is your laravel code expects the file's POST name to be `userUpload`? In that case you probably need to use `const formData = {userUpload: selectedFile}` (you probably have `$request->get('userUpload')->getClientOriginalName()` in your laravel code)

Comment: @ChrisG yeah just tried that, but still getting the same result :(

Comment: You need to `var_dump($request)` or something to find out how to get to the file. And the capitalization of the `name` has to match exactly.

Comment: Why are you trying to encode the FormData instance as JSON?

Answer (score 0):

you should check your header content-type that should be set to
multipart/form-data